# Create horizontal line in table cell in latex [pics]

Tags: tables

So basically i was wondering how id go about getting the table below to have a line across from the control column to the justification column for each 'newline' within the pre-existing row.

Extra brownie points if it works for longtable and is simple!

```
\setlength\LTleft{-2cm}
\setlength\LTright{-2cm}
\begin{tabular}
{ | p{1cm} | p{2cm} | p{1cm} | p{4cm} | p{0.5cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} | p{1.5cm} | p{1.5cm} | } 
\hline
Risk Tag & Risk & Risk Severity & Control & Cost & Benefit & Chosen & Residual Risk & Justification \\
\hline
R01 & Eavesdropping on local network & Critical & Prevent C1 - Patch wireless router - if patch available \newline  Prevent C2 - Use https everywhere browser plugin where available & L & H & Y & L & Free and Effective\\
\hline
R02 & MITM on local network & High\\
\hline
R03 & Infection of Phones via Exploit & High \\
\hline
\hline
 \end{tabular}
```

heres the image, i want the line in between the two prevents if possible

[image: heres the image, i want the line in between the two prevents if possible]

Comment: `\cline{4-5}` ?

Comment: ya bro that doesn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: what means "doent work"? you should clarify your question, maybe add a sketch, what you like to achieve. but in the first, extend your code snippet to complete small document, beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. help us to help you.

Comment: hey zarko, you seem a little salty, maybe consider leaving your house

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place the second "prevent" in a separate row, you can use `\cline` as suggested in a comment. You might need `\multirow` for the "Eavesdropping" cell though.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1cm}
\begin{document}
{\small
\begin{longtable}
{ | p{1cm} | p{2cm} | p{1cm} | p{4cm} | p{0.5cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} | p{1.5cm} | p{1.5cm} | } 
\hline
Risk Tag & Risk & Risk Severity & Control & Cost & Benefit & Chosen & Residual Risk & Justification \\
\hline
R01 & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{Eavesdropping on local network}} & Critical & Prevent C1 -- Patch wireless router -- if patch available & L & H & Y & L & Free and Effective\\ \cline{4-9}
 &  & & Prevent C2 - Use https everywhere browser plugin where available &&&&& \\ 
\hline
R02 & MITM on local network & High\\
\hline
R03 & Infection of Phones via Exploit & High \\
\hline
\hline
\end{longtable}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: incredible, nice !

Comment: @dipl0, please tell me now, what not work  considering my comment?

Comment: @Zarko The two "prevent" sentences were  in the same cell.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., i suspect this ... anyway, OP's table has other issues too.  it is to wide to be fit in text width, i would consider `booktabs` and remove vertical lines, etc :-) however for me is now time for go to sleep ...

Comment: hey zarko! ya seem a bit sarko!